# Got to view when push notification opened on ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, onesignal

I am working on ionic app and I want to push to a page when push notification opened, but app did not navigate to view.

**my code so far:**

**app.component.ts**

```
 this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe((payload) => {

         this.categoryService.goToView.next(post_id)
    });
```

**home.ts**

```
this.categoryService.goToView.subscribe(id=>{

    this.categoryService.getPostsFromServer({include:id}).subscribe(item=>{

      this.itemTapped(item);
    })
  })
```

**itemTapped**

```
itemTapped(item) {

    this.navCtrl.push(ViewPage, {
            item: item
        });
  }
```

any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

have your tried deep links the [ionic plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/)

i think it will help in this case.